# Цикл While не работает с логическими операциями

Tags: python, python-3.x, if, while

Кто нибудь может объяснить неучу, почему при таком написании кода не работает условие в цикле While при втором уровне сложности (количество попыток уже превышает 5, а выход из цикла всё равно не происходит)? Знаю, что код можно написать по-другому, но интересно в чём здесь ошибка

```
import random

number = random.randint(1,100)
user_number = None

i = 0

level = int(input('Какой будет уровень сложности? Введите 1 или 2: '))

if level == 1:

    while user_number != number:
        user_number = int(input('Попробуйте угадать число от 1 до 100 '))
        if user_number > number:
            print('Ваше число больше загаданного!')
        elif user_number < number:
            print('Ваше число меньше загаданного!')
        else:
            print('Победа!')

elif level == 2:

    while (user_number != number) or (i != 5):
        i += 1
        print(f'Попытка № {i}')
        user_number = int(input('Попробуйте угадать число от 1 до 100 '))
        if user_number > number:
            print('Ваше число больше загаданного!')
        elif user_number < number:
            print('Ваше число меньше загаданного!')
        else:
            print('Победа!')
    if i == 5:
        print('Вы истратили количество попыток!')
```

Comment: Рекомендую инициализировать счетчик попыток не нулем, а единицей. И инкремент делать не вначале попытки, а в конце. Тогда вы избежите проблемы лишней попытки во втором уровне

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonicam это stackoverflow на русском, Поэтому комментарии нужно оставлять на русском языке

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нарушена логика.

Сейчас - продолжать, пока или первое или второе, т.е. для остановки нужно нарушение двух условий одновременно.

Чтобы останавливаться по любому условию, требуется `and`

```
while (user_number != number) and (i != 5):
```

Comment: Получилось! Спасибо! Я думал, что такой код будет значить, что должны выполняться одновременно оба условия, чтобы выйти из цикла

Comment: Капец тупанул. Пока хотя бы одно из этих условий было правдой, цикл продолжался) Теперь догнал